# Qt Creator, how to set an image as background picture

Tags: image, qt, background, qt-creator

I would just like to set the background of my qt creater window to a picture which I have saved on my computer. I have tried right clicking the background, going into Change styleSheet and than clicking add resource but nothing comes up and I can not search for the file on my computer.

Comment: This post may be useful: https://forum.qt.io/topic/1378/is-it-possible-to-set-a-background-image-to-a-widget/17

Answer (score 1):

Add the file to your **resources.qrc** file, which is located in your project source folder , in a way like:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
    <file>your_image.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

After, in your window/widget constructor, load the image to a pixmap so it's stored for other uses (like setting the background)

```
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.load(":/your_image.png")

//scaling the image, optional. See the documentation for more options
pixmap = pixmap.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(QPalette::Window, pixmap);
this.setPalette(palette);
```

Then you can implement resize events, paint events etc, to play with your pixmap background image..